# DB2 for IBM i (AS400) - SQL

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Two tables A (daily Loan Transaction table) and B (daily eod Loan Balance table).

Trying to write a select statement in DB2 AS400 to display daily loan transactions, eod Loan Balance and beginning loan balance (prior day) for selected date range.

Below query would give me daily loan transactions and eod loan balance. But need some help on modifying the query below to calculate beginning loan balance as well (balance as of 02/28/2015) for date range 03/01/2015 to 03/31/2015 selected.

```
select A.*, -- daily loan transactions
       B.EOD_Loan_Balance
from A 
  inner join B 
   on A.date_id = B.date_id 
    and A.Loan_num = B.Loan_num
where a.date_id between 03/01/2015 to 03/31/2015
```

Note that previous day should be business day so if 02/28/2015 is not a business day then we need to pull eod balance of day before that and which should be a business day.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, you also want to select `EOD_Loan_Balance where date_id = ('2015-03-01' - 1 day)`. Or are dates not contiguous?

Comment: Beginning loan balance which is previous day eod balance of date 03/01/2015 i.e  ('2015-03-01' - 1 day)  and it should be a BUSINESS DAY. If previous day is not a business day then have to get the eod balance from day before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many tasks that are easy to do with a "calender" or "dates" table...

```
select D.*,
       B.EOD_Loan_Balance,
       E.EOD_Loan_Balance,
from MY_CALENDAR_TABLE C
     join daily_trans D on c.date = d.date 
     join eod_bal B on c.date - 1 day= b.date and d.loan_num = b.loan_num
     join eod_bal E on c.date = e.date and d.loan_num = e.loan_num
where c.date between 2015-03-01 and 2015-03-31
  and c.is_business_day = 1;
```

**--Edit--**
Looking back at this, I realized that it doesn't quite work; the join from beginning balance won't give you the prior **businsess day**.

Luckily, the flexibility of a calendar table comes to the rescue.  Just include a `PRIOR_BUSINESS_DAY` column in your calendar table.

Then the SQL becomes:

```
select D.*,
       B.EOD_Loan_Balance,
       E.EOD_Loan_Balance,
from MY_CALENDAR_TABLE C
     join daily_trans D on c.date = d.date
     join eod_bal B on c.prior_buisiness_day = b.date 
           and d.loan_num = b.loan_num
     join eod_bal E on c.date = e.date
           and d.loan_num = e.loan_num
where c.date between 2015-03-01 and 2015-03-31
  and c.is_business_day = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
select A.*, -- daily loan transactions
       B.EOD_Loan_Balance,
       C.EOD_Loan_Balance,
from A 
  inner join B 
   on A.date_id = B.date_id 
    and A.Loan_num = B.Loan_num
  LEFT OUTER join C
   on A.Loan_num = C.Loan_num
where a.date_id between '2015-03-01' to '2015-03-31'
and c.date_id = CASE 
                  WHEN DAYOFWEEK('2015-03-01') = 1 THEN '2015-03-01' - 2 days 'Sunday --> Friday
                  WHEN DAYOFWEEK('2015-03-01') = 2 THEN '2015-03-01' - 3 days 'Monday --> Friday
                  ELSE                                  '2015-03-01' - 1 day ' Previous day
                END
```

Untested as I don't have a DB2 instance handy.

**EDIT**  Revised to allow for weekends as mentioned in comments.

Comment: The above provided not working in the following cases: 1) If EOD balance in C don;t exist for previous day then daily transactions happened today won;t display. To avoid that if use Left join then we can not apply where condition on c.date_id. 2) If the previous day is not a business day

Comment: That works fine except in a case where the purpose of left outer join exists. Because using where condition on table left outer join'd to some other table would work as inner join. For eg: I want to see daily transactions even prior business day balance in C don;t exist and it can be achieved with left outer join but with where condition on C.date_id not displaying the daily transactions.

Comment: And what happens if you have a month with a holiday on a weekday?   Having a pre-caclulated calendar table is the best way to handle these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Charles, OP didn't specify what defines a "business day". And it wasn't even included in the original question. I agree that for serious business uses you need a robust but flexible solution (not hardcoding things into SQL). But on this site you never know if you are helping a beginner with homework, or a professional real-world problem. So, I don't intend to solve aspects of the problem which haven't been included in the question.

Comment: @Turophile, I can understand not accounting for business day given it wasn't in the original question.  Would be nice if the OP would update the question with the requirement.  But I'd argue that student or new professional, introducing the calendar table concept for this class problem is always the right answer.

Comment: @Charles - this is a real world problem and after analyzing data realized that there is no eod balances available for non-business days so included the condition of prior day balance should be from business day after posted the question. Anyway updated the question now and I am going with the idea of using calendar table. Thanks again for both of your time.